# Creating a PIVOT SQL table from two row values into two columns, dynamic amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My query

```
select
    custname, 
    case 
        when date < '11/26/2023' then -1 
        else datepart(wk, date) 
    end 'week#', 
    sum(amount) sales,
    count(salesid) orders 
from 
    SalesTable 
inner join 
    CustomerTable c on salestable.CustID = c.CustID
where 
    date < '1/27/2024' 
    and c.CustID = 10285 or c.CustID = -2
group by 
    c.custid, custname, [address],
    case when date < '11/26/2023' then -1 else datepart(wk, date) end,
    case when date < '11/26/2023' then '11/25/2023' else DATEADD(dd,7-(DATEPART(dw, date)), date) end 
order by 
    1, 2
```

This gets all customer's sales (sum amount, week number, amount orders) by one week any row.

Like this:

| custname | week# | sales | orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustAAA | -1 | 974697.41 | 62013 |
| CustAAA | 1 | 10.01 | 5 |
| CustAAA | 2 | 10 | 2 |
| CustAAA | 2 | 372.95 | 11 |
| CustAAA | 3 | 70.86 | 13 |
| CustAAA | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| CustAAA | 4 | 8.08 | 2 |
| CustAAA | 5 | 20 | 6 |
| CustAAA | 48 | 0 | 38 |
| CustAAA | 49 | 84.27 | 2 |
| CustXYZ | -1 | 12.12 | 1 |
| CustXYZ | 1 | 22.59 | 1 |
| CustXYZ | 4 | 117.9 | 1 |
| CustXYZ | 48 | 19.3 | 1 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qC7j.png)

How do I `PIVOT` one row per customer, 'week' number as column-> amount, 'week' number as column -> orders.

And again the next week number, as shown in this example:

| custname | week -1 sales | week -1 orders | week 1 sales | week 1 orders | week 2 sales | week 2 orders | week 3 sales | week 3 orders | week 4 sales | week 4 orders | week 5 sales | week 5 orders | week 48 sales | week 48 orders | week 49 sales | week 49 orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustAAA | 974697.41 | 62013 | 10.01 | 5 | 382.95 | 13 | 70.86 | 16 | 8.08 | 2 | 20 | 6 | 0 | 38 | 84.27 | 2 |
| CustXYZ | 12.12 | 1 | 22.59 | 1 |  |  |  |  | 117.9 | 1 |  |  | 19.3 | 1 |  |  |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8sHj.png)

Comment: Please **DO NOT** use images, the editor provides tabular markdown options specifically for displaying data.

Comment: When using literal dates as well, don't use ambiguous date formats; it can result in inconsistent behaviour. The above, for example, would likely fail for anyone not in North America.

Comment: Also it took me a couple reads to work out `week#` is an alias. Don't use string literal for aliases, some of the syntax are deprecated, as they have inconsistent behaviour . Try to avoid aliases that don't need to be delimited identified as well (and if you "must" use brackets (`[]`) or double quotes (`"`)). Also, at least for columns, it's generally preferred to use `Alias = Expression` or `Expression AS Alias` syntax.

Comment: Here is a fiddle I am working on for a more dynamic solution https://dbfiddle.uk/x3_Z1bzk

Comment: @DaleK TY for the table building! It's so cumbersome.

Comment: @ThomA you right, Thanks for the knowledge enrichment, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a strategy from [Another Dynamic SQL CrossTab Stored Procedure](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2005/05/02/4842/) by Jeff Smith. I was able to use the heart of his stored procedure to create  dynamic (no hard coded columns) pivot tables. Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vS4gKjaV) showing my work.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

CREATE TABLE CustomerSales 
(
    custname    VARCHAR(512),
    week#   INT,
    sales   decimal(10,2),
    orders  INT
);

INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', -1, 974697.41, '62013');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 1, 10.01, '5');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 2, 10, '2');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 2, 372.95, '11');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 3, 70.86, '13');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 3, 0, '3');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 4, 8.08, '2');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 5, 20, '6');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 48, 0, '38');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustAAA', 49, 84.27, '2');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustXYZ', -1, 12.12, '1');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustXYZ', 1, 22.59, '1');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustXYZ', 4, 117.9, '1');
INSERT INTO CustomerSales (custname, week#, sales, orders) VALUES ('CustXYZ', 48, 19.3, '1');

Select * from CustomerSales

   Declare @Select varchar(800) ='SELECT CustName, week#, sales, orders FROM CustomerSales';
    Declare @PivotCol varchar(100) = 'week#';
    Declare @Summaries varchar(100) = 'Sum(CASE sales WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE sales END)[ Sales],SUM(orders)[ Orders]';
    Declare  @GroupBy varchar(100)  = 'CustName';
    Declare  @OrderBy varchar(100) = 'CustName';
    
    declare @Vals varchar(8000);
    set @Vals = '';
   
    create table #temp (Pivot1 int) 

    insert into #temp
    exec ('SELECT distinct convert(varchar(100),' + @PivotCol + ') as PIVOT1 FROM (' + @Select +') A')
      
    Select @Vals = @Vals + ', ' +
       replace(replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PivotCol + '=''' + 
                 CONVERT(varchar(10), Pivot1) + ''' THEN '),')[', ' END) as [Week ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), Pivot1)   )
    FROM #Temp
    ORDER BY Pivot1

    drop table #Temp

    exec ('SELECT ' + @GroupBY + @vals + ' FROM (' + @Select + ') A GROUP BY  ' + @GroupBy + ' ORDER BY ' + @OrderBy )

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

| CustName | Week -1 Sales | Week -1 Orders | Week 1 Sales | Week 1 Orders | Week 2 Sales | Week 2 Orders | Week 3 Sales | Week 3 Orders | Week 4 Sales | Week 4 Orders | Week 5 Sales | Week 5 Orders | Week 48 Sales | Week 48 Orders | Week 49 Sales | Week 49 Orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustAAA | 974697.41 | 62013 | 10.01 | 5 | 382.95 | 13 | 70.86 | 16 | 8.08 | 2 | 20.00 | 6 | 0.00 | 38 | 84.27 | 2 |
| CustXYZ | 12.12 | 1 | 22.59 | 1 | null | null | null | null | 117.90 | 1 | null | null | 19.30 | 1 | null | null |

Comment: TY for the Dynamic solution.
BUT something in the Orders columns doesn't match with the data.

Comment: Corrected. COUNT(orders) replaced with SUM(orders)

Comment: @user23327878  Week sorting, decimal format,  and column header captions corrected.

Comment: It's Perfect. TY So much.
(the truth is that the high weeks should be first because it's from the previous year.. anyway I changed it to the full date of the first day of any week)

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions like this it's very helpful to provide example DDL and DML in an easy to understand and reproduce format:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (custname VARCHAR(20), week INT, sales DECIMAL(10,2), orders INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (custname, week, sales, orders) VALUES
('CustAAA', -1 , 974697.41 , 62013), ('CustAAA', 1 , 10.01 , 5), ('CustAAA', 2 , 10 , 2), 
('CustAAA', 2 , 372.95 , 11), ('CustAAA', 3 , 70.86 , 13), ('CustAAA', 3 , 0 , 3), 
('CustAAA', 4 , 8.08 , 2), ('CustAAA', 5 , 20 , 6), ('CustAAA', 48 , 0 , 38), 
('CustAAA', 49 , 84.27 , 2), ('CustXYZ', -1 , 12.12 , 1), ('CustXYZ', 1 , 22.59 , 1), 
('CustXYZ', 4 , 117.9 , 1), ('CustXYZ', 48 , 19.3 , 1);

SELECT p.custname, MAX(p.sales1) AS Sales1, MAX(p.orders1) AS Orders1, MAX(p.sales2) AS Sales2, MAX(p.orders2) AS Orders2, 
                   MAX(p.sales3) AS Sales3, MAX(p.orders3) AS Orders3, MAX(p.sales53) AS Sales53, MAX(p.orders53) AS Orders53
  FROM (
SELECT i.sales, i.orders, i.custname, 
       'sales' + CAST(week AS VARCHAR(2)) AS WeekSales, 'orders' + CAST(week AS VARCHAR(2)) AS WeekOrders
  FROM @Table i
       ) a
    PIVOT (
           SUM(sales) FOR WeekSales IN (sales1, sales2, sales3, sales53)
          ) p
    PIVOT (
           SUM(orders) FOR WeekOrders IN (orders1, orders2, orders3, orders53)
          ) p
 GROUP BY p.custname;
```

Here we've reproduced the week column twice, once for each pivot we want to do.
Then, it's just a case of producing the list of each of the values, and aggregating as required.

| custname | Sales1 | Orders1 | Sales2 | Orders2 | Sales3 | Orders3 | Sales53 | Orders53 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CustAAA | 10.01 | 5 | 372.95 | 11 | 70.86 | 13 |  |  |
| CustXYZ | 22.59 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

To pivot your data so that each customer's sales and orders are displayed in separate columns for each week, you can use conditional aggregation with the CASE statement to pivot the data dynamically. Here's how you can achieve this:

```sql
SELECT
    custname,
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = -1 THEN sales END) AS [week -1 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = -1 THEN orders END) AS [week -1 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 1 THEN sales END) AS [week 1 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 1 THEN orders END) AS [week 1 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 2 THEN sales END) AS [week 2 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 2 THEN orders END) AS [week 2 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 3 THEN sales END) AS [week 3 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 3 THEN orders END) AS [week 3 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 4 THEN sales END) AS [week 4 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 4 THEN orders END) AS [week 4 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 5 THEN sales END) AS [week 5 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 5 THEN orders END) AS [week 5 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 48 THEN sales END) AS [week 48 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 48 THEN orders END) AS [week 48 orders],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 49 THEN sales END) AS [week 49 sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN week = 49 THEN orders END) AS [week 49 orders]
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.custname,
        CASE WHEN date < '11/26/2023' THEN -1 ELSE datepart(wk, date) END AS week,
        amount AS sales,
        COUNT(salesid) AS orders
    FROM
        SalesTable
    INNER JOIN
        CustomerTable c ON SalesTable.CustID = c.CustID
    WHERE
        date < '1/27/2024'
        AND (c.CustID = 10285 OR c.CustID = -2)
    GROUP BY
        c.custname,
        CASE WHEN date < '11/26/2023' THEN -1 ELSE datepart(wk, date) END,
        amount
) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    custname;
```

This query first calculates the week number based on the date, then aggregates the sales and orders for each customer and week. Finally, it pivots the data using conditional aggregation to display sales and orders for each week in separate columns.

Adjust the column and table names as necessary based on your actual schema.